# How to output non case-sensitive array elements

Tags: ruby

Here is the test case

```
a = ["Barack", "Obama"]
b = ["John", "Obama"]
```

Now if I do `a & b` . It gives me `["Obama"]`. The common one gets rendered.

Although if this is the scenario

```
a = ["Barack", "Obama"]
b = ["John", "obama"] # See O is not capitalized here
```

And I do `a & b`. I will get a empty array `[]` as an ouput. I understand why. Although, how to get around this and make it so its case sensitive non case-sensitive ?

Thanks

**Update:** Its not necessary it will be always in downcase. `a` could have downcase string and `b` have all upcase strings or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't bullet-proof, and it doesn't yield the original array values, but it might be Good Enough™:

```
common = a.map(&:downcase) & b.map(&:downcase)
```

To retrieve original values that satisfy the test you could try something like this:

```
require 'set'

xs = ["Barack", "Obama"]
ys = ["John", "Obama"]

univ = ys.map(&:downcase).to_set
hits = xs.select { |x| univ.include?(x.downcase) }
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if your array contains **only** strings. (Or a custom object that responds to `downcase`)

Comment: @FMc do you know a way i could yield the original array values?

Comment: @FMc Else it pretty much defeats the purpose of what i am doing here. Although it works but a way to retrieve to the original values would be great. THanks

Comment: isnt there a way to use casecmp? which is much more faster?

Answer (score 2):

This works for a more general case:

```
class Array
  def intersection other, &block
    block ||= proc{|x| x }
    res = []
    transformed_other = other.map(&block)
    self.each do |x|
      res << x if transformed_other.include?(block.call(x))
    end
    res
  end
end
```

Now with your test data:

```
a = ["Barack", "Obama"]
b = ["John", "obama"]
```

You can either intersect the arrays normally (equivalent to `a & b`):

```
a.intersection(b)
#=> []
```

Or you can provide a block:

```
a.intersection(b, &:downcase)
#=> ["Obama"]
```

This method will keep the original values from the first array, `a` in this case.

Comment: but i would if there isnt a downcase it would be an issue. Or maybe I have to issue the command twice. Lets see if I can tweak it. Thanks though :)

Comment: It converts everything to downcased strings for comparison but then it actually returns the original values from the lefthand array. So it will also work if everything is capitalized, go try it out ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another cut at the general approach using group_by on the concatenation of the two lists. The results contain the original representation of the element in the receiver.

```
class Array
  def intersect_by other, &block
    (self + other).
    group_by(&block).
    values.
    select{ |v| v.size == 2 }.
    map(&:first)
  end
end

a.intersect_by(b, &:downcase)
=> ["Obama"]
```